# Spring Integration File Poller with Watch Service and LastModifiedFileListFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I was wondering if anyone would know if I could use the watch service in a FileInboundChannelAdapter along with a LastModifiedFileListFilter?

The sample code below is giving me fairly inconsistent results. Sometimes the file just sits in the folder and remains unprocessed.

I suspect that the watch service might be incompatible with the LastModifiedFileListFilter. For e.g.

- If the LastModifiedFileListfilter is set to look for files at least 5
  seconds old, and the poller is set to poll every 10 seconds.
- At the 9th second, a file could be created in the watched folder.
- At 10 seconds the poller queries the watch service to find out what
  changed    in the past 10 seconds.
- It finds the newly created file.
- The newly    created has a last modified time of -1 second, so it
  does not process    it.
- At 20 seconds, the poller queries the watch
  service a second    time, this time it does not see the unprocessed
  file as it was    created more than 10 seconds ago.

Would anyone else have any experience with this? Would there be a recommended way to get around this issue and allow me to verify that the file has been fully written before proceeding?

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow ftpInputFileWatcher()
{
    return IntegrationFlows.from(ftpInboundFolder(), filePoller())
            .handle()
            /*abbreviated*/
            .get();
}

private FileInboundChannelAdapterSpec ftpInboundFolder() {
     LastModifiedFileListFilter lastModifiedFileListFilter = new LastModifiedFileListFilter();
    lastModifiedFileListFilter.setAge(5);

    return Files.inboundAdapter(inboundFolder)
            .preventDuplicates(false)
            .useWatchService(true)
            .filter(fileAgeFilterToPreventPrematurePickup());
}

protected Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec> filePoller(){
    return poller -> poller.poller((Function<PollerFactory, PollerSpec>) p -> p.fixedRate(2000));
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's good catch!

Right they are not compatible. The WatchService is event-based and store files from the events into the internal queue. When the poller triggers its action, it polls files from that queue and applies its filters. Since `LastModifiedFileListFilter` discards the file and there is no any events for it any more, we won't see that file again.

Please, raise a JIRA on the matter and we'll think how to be .

Meanwhile as a workaround do not use WatchService for this kind of logic.

Comment: Thanks Artem, I've logged INT-4351.

Comment: Hi Artem, it looks like it is not possible to use a different directory scanner besides the default. Please see bug: INT-4352.

Comment: Just to clarify, the reason I needed the watch service is so that I can pick up changes to files in sub-directories. I went with the watch service as that was the recommendation by the Spring docs. However, after encountering the issue above, I wanted to switch to a RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner. That's when I noticed that you can't actually use a different scanner.

Comment: Yeah! That is good catch as well! However there is a workaround for you using `FileReadingMessageSource` directly instead of `Files` Java DSL API. Let me know if at least that works for you! Also bear in mind that there is `RecursiveDirectoryScanner` since 5.0

Comment: I've worked around it by prepping my file in a temp folder, and then moving it to the watched directory when it is ready. Given that a file move in Unix is an instant operation (it is essentially a rename) if it is on the same file system, I think this would work. Thanks for good work!